# Handlebars compile function com options parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

Eu quero minificar meu template durante o período de compilação do mesmo no NodeJS

Pesquisando sobre eu descobri que o `handlebars.compile(templateLoaded);` tem mais opções além do parâmetro template. Eu gostaria de saber como passar o parametro minify corretamente e quais são as outras opções que poderiam ser passadas.

[Neste link](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/271106d43fae96fc1287898568d000b871f19084/lib/handlebars/compiler/javascript-compiler.js#L46-L48), as linhas em destaque permitem isso.

[Fiz a mesma pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878242/handlebars-compile-function-with-options-parameters), caso alguém queira responder lá também ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de pensarmos em compilar o Handlebars, pense em minificar HTML.

*Ok, mas e as propriedades do Handlebars, como é que ficam?*

Na verdade, está na hora de unir o útil ao agradável: utilizar um minifier que compile HTML por trás. Quem faz exatamente isso é [este helper](https://www.npmjs.org/package/handlebars-helper-minify).

Comment: E as opções para não precisar usar o helper. Não consigo nada esclarecedor sobre ela, se tem algo no formato JSON que eu possa enviar.

Comment: Você não consegue fazer isso diretamente. Isso, aliás, é explicado no próprio site através [desta documentação](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html). Você pode fazer a minificação através da linha de comando com o helper que lhe passei.